# SUM but only the last instance / occurrence if there are duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

This is a sample of office Stats and I want to SUM all of the "Dizziness" from C2:H6 but only take the LAST instance if there is a duplicate in a Patient Name. I've seen somewhere posted SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10/COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10&"")) for finding the first instance, but not the last. Note: Because this is a patient database, there will be multiple duplicates.

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaGNH.png)

```
Timestamp   Name    Condition 1 Rate    Condition 2 Rate    Condition 3 Rate
3/6/18      Test 2  Dizziness   5   Fatigue     5   Fainting    5
3/7/18      Test 3  Sciatica    3   Dizziness   5   Tinnitus    10
3/8/18      Test 2  Dizziness   5   Fainting    6   Fatigue     6
3/9/18      Test 4  Neck Pain   6   Sciatica    6   Vertigo     6
3/10/18     Test 2  Fatigue     8   Fainting    8   Dizziness   10

        DIZZINESS   15      25
```

I know my result should be 15 from Test 2 and Test 3, but I don't want to capture Test 2's duplicate from other dates which would give me a total of 25 (was using =SUMIFS(D2:H6,C2:G6,C8). Help please?

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,B2:B6))*($C$2:$G$6=C8),D2:H6)
```

Earlier versions:

Use a helper column to store the max date, put this in I2 and copy down:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$6/($B$2:$B$6=B2),1)
```

Then you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:H6),($C$2:$G$6=C8)*(A2:A6=I2:I6))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @scott Craner! Thanks also for making my post more readable.  I forgot to mention (edited my post), but how do I do this will multiple duplicates? This will be a patient database with hundreds of individuals and most of them will be retaking the questionnaire at least 3-4 times. I am also using an earlier version than Office 365.

Comment: @James324 use the second method with the helper column and adjust the references to match.

Comment: With method 2 I'm trying to create a reference with the helper cell =AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$6/($B$2:$B$6=B2),1). If I have duplicate of Test 3 and Test 4, in addition to test 2, how would the helper cells look like if I'm still trying to add up for the condition, Dizziness? Not sure how to proceed. Would I create multiple columns of helper cells for each duplicate patient name?

Comment: No only the one. It will find the latest date for each patient.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just realized my earlier comment was pointless. Thank YOU!